# How I can change data in prisma.schema, without losing data after migration?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

When I changed prisma.schema and run:

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
```

My Postgres lost all data. Can I run another command which doesn't remove my data? What is best for me in this situation?

Answer (score -1):

From the prisma.io documentation:

> Prisma Migrate is an imperative database schema migration tool that enables you to keep your database schema in sync with your Prisma schema as it evolves and
> main existing data in your database
> Prisma Migrate generates a history of .sql migration files, and plays a role in both development and deployment.

This means that the `prisma migrate` command is supposed to be syncing the data from the model with the one in the database, adding/removing rows if needed, etc.

Perhaps the command you are looking for is `prisma db push`? They both have similar uses and aspects, one is for dev, one isn't.